# In Javascript, How to detect the character case (upper/lower) in keydown & keyup events?

Tags: jquery, case-sensitive, keydown, keyup

I need to detect the case of characters in event keydown and keyup

```
$('body').keydown(
    function(event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        var char = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        console.log(char + " is down pressed");
    }
);

$('body').keyup(
    function(event) {
        var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
        var char = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        console.log(char + " is up pressed");
    }
);
```

You may try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8dqwW/

It's always returning the upper case letter even if no caps lock is pressed.

How can I detect the letter pressed with its case, either upper or lower in those two events ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keyup` and `keydown` cannot detect the upper/lower case.

Only `keypress` can do so !

Comment: you can detect whether shift is pressed, as a hack.  but not caps lock :(

Comment: For infor, keypress is now [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) :(

Answer (score 5):

## Use `event.key` and modern JS!

*No number codes* anymore. You can check key directly. For example `"Enter"`, `"LeftArrow"`, `"r"`, or `"R"`. `"keypress"`, `"keydown"`, or `"keyup"` will all work.

```
document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    const key = event.key;
    const keyLower = key.toLowerCase();

    // Check it is a char between A-Z, not numbers, etc.
    if (key.length !== 1 || keyLower < "a" || keyLower > "z") {
        return;
    }

    // Check for case
    const isUpperCase = (key !== keyLower);
});
```

You could simplify it with a regex

```
const key = event.key;
const isLowerCaseLetter = (/[a-z]/.test(key));
const isUpperCaseLetter = (/[A-Z]/.test(key));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the character is still the same after converting it to uppercase, it was uppercase to begin with :

```
if (fromCharCode(e.which).toUpperCase() == fromCharCode(e.which))
```

As jQuery normalizes `e.which`, and the `keypress` event works a little differently, I'd do something like :

```
$('body').on({
    keypress: function(e) {
        var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which),
            isUpper = char == char.toUpperCase();
        console.log(char + ' is pressed' + (isUpper ? ' and uppercase' : ''))
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t8Ybs/2/)

Comment: Your first code isn't helpful, as the e.which is already upper case, so always the boolean expression will resolves to true. And your second code uses keypress not keydown, and this will not help at all in keyup.

Comment: @AshrafBashir - that's because keyup and keydown has no distinction of wether or not the character is upper or lower case, it returns the same code for both, so using those events it's not possible to know if the character is upper or lower. You could listen for the shift key, but that's no guarantee either.

Comment: It's always nice when the one who asked the question, posts his own answer a few months later, saying the exact same thing, and then accepts that instead !