# Changing keyDown presses to lower case

Tags: javascript, input, lowercase

I am trying to compare 2 characters (or key codes) to check if the letter on the screen is the same as the pressed character.

Sadly, all the keyDown results are in upper-case, and I would like to know if there's a different way that gets input as lower-case instead of manually changing all the input.

Here's my code:

```
document.onkeydown = function keyDown(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;

  if (e.keyCode == currentCharacter.charCodeAt(0)) {
      // Input matches the current character.
  } else {
      // Input does not match the current character.
  }
}
```

In this example, e.keyCode always returns the keycode for an upper-case version of the character I pressed.

Comment: post some code for us to see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17027405/2627160),

Using `keyPress` event rather than `keyDown` might be the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I'll accept the answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

How about converting the keyCode to a char, and the lowercase it..

```
document.onkeydown = function keyDown(e) {
  if (!e) e = window.event;
var keyPressed =  String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase()
  if (keyPressed == 'a') {
      // Input matches the current character.
  } else {
      // Input does not match the current character.
  }
}
```